# AWS SSH with Public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, ip, vagrant

I am trying to use Vagrant to create AWS EC2 instances and it works great until it gets to the SSH part. Vagrant uses the public IP to try and SSH and that doesn't work with the EC2 instances I have created, I have to use the public DNS.

I opened 22 to every IP briefly and it did work, so its something to do with the firewall but I can't figure out what IPs I need to open (I have tired the (default) VPC CIDRs)

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to open the SSH port in NACL and SecurityGroup for the IP of your Vagrant machine. So figure out the IP of your Vagrant server (say X.X.X.X) and open port 22 for X.X.X.X/32 in the NACL as well as in SecurityGroup.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! The default NACL comes as open for everything, and it is still like that. I eventually found a fix by making Vagrant use the private IP instead.

Comment: Great, it worked for you.

However, you should not keep all the ports open in your NACL for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

By adding the following line into the Vagrantfile, it forced Vagrant to use the servers private IP instead and therefore could SSH successfully.

```
aws.ssh_host_attribute = :private_ip_address
```

Hope this helps other people will the same issue